# Unable to search and replace the values using column headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a vba script that will search for the ***_*** in all the cells fallen under `Crude Items` column. However, when it finds one, it will split the values from ***_*** and place the rest in corresponding cells fallen under `Refined Ones` column.

I've tried with the following which is doing the job flawlessly but I wish to search and replace the values using column headers:

```
Sub CopyAndReplace()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        If cel.value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cel(1, 3).Address) = Split(cel, "_")(1)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

To let you visualize how the sheet might look like:

[image]

***How can I search and replace the values using column headers?***

Comment: Are you working through an actual table?

Comment: Can there be more than one underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are after, but a few important mentions...

Try to always use at least a worksheet qualifier when writing your code. How else is your program going to know explicitly where you would like it to operate?

I have changed your process slightly, but again, not sure if this is exactly what you are after. See below code.

```
Sub SplitByHeader()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim crudeHeader As Range, refinedHeader As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet


    'set ws
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'set header ranges
    Set crudeHeader = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Crude Items", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set refinedHeader = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Refined Ones", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    'simple error handler
    If crudeHeader Is Nothing Or refinedHeader Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, crudeHeader.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(i, crudeHeader.Column).Value <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, refinedHeader.Column).Value = Split(ws.Cells(i, crudeHeader.Column).Value, "_")(1)
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check out my code that I've pasted while creating this post? I used this line `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cel(1, 3).Address) = Split(cel, "_")(1)` to qualify the worksheet. Ain't that what you meant?

Comment: @MITHU in your code you fail to qualify a worksheet in the range you are looping through and checking. You are qualifying a worksheet when setting the values, but your check is unqualified.

Comment: Thanks @Dean. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this one with the code below:

[image]

It is a good idea to add additional check to the condition, like this - `If myCell.Value <> "" And InStr(1, myCell, "_") Then` to avoid starting from `A2`.

The idea is that the `LocateValueCol` locates the column of the first row, which has the string, passed to it. Knowing this, it works ok.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyAndReplace()

    Dim searchColumn As Long
    searchColumn = LocateValueCol("SearchCol", Worksheets(1))

    Dim replaceColumn As Long
    replaceColumn = LocateValueCol("ReplaceCol", Worksheets(1))

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long

    With Worksheets(1)
        lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, searchColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each myCell In .Range(.Cells(1, searchColumn), .Cells(lastCell, searchColumn))
            If myCell.Value <> "" And InStr(1, myCell, "_") Then
                .Cells(myCell.Row, replaceColumn) = Split(myCell, "_")(1)
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

This is the function, locating the columns. ([If you have ideas for improvement, feel free to make a PR here](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/LastThings.vb)):

```
Public Function LocateValueCol(ByVal textTarget As String, _
                ByRef wksTarget As Worksheet, _
                Optional rowNeeded As Long = 1, _
                Optional moreValuesFound As Long = 1, _
                Optional lookForPart = False, _
                Optional lookUpToBottom = True) As Long

    Dim valuesFound As Long
    Dim localRange  As Range
    Dim myCell  As Range

    LocateValueCol = -999
    valuesFound = moreValuesFound
    Set localRange = wksTarget.Range(wksTarget.Cells(rowNeeded, 1), wksTarget.Cells(rowNeeded, Columns.Count))

    For Each myCell In localRange
        If lookForPart Then
            If textTarget = Left(myCell, Len(textTarget)) Then
                If valuesFound = 1 Then
                    LocateValueCol = myCell.Column
                    If lookUpToBottom Then Exit Function
                Else
                    Decrement valuesFound
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If textTarget = Trim(myCell) Then
                If valuesFound = 1 Then
                    LocateValueCol = myCell.Column
                    If lookUpToBottom Then Exit Function
                Else
                    Decrement valuesFound
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

End Function

Private Sub Increment(ByRef valueToIncrement As Variant, Optional incrementWith As Double = 1)

    valueToIncrement = valueToIncrement + incrementWith

End Sub

Private Sub Decrement(ByRef valueToDecrement As Variant, Optional decrementWith As Double = 1)

    valueToDecrement = valueToDecrement - decrementWith

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun using regex and dynamically finding header columns. You can swop out the regex based function for your own and still have the dynamic column finding.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, inputs(), re As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim inputColumn As Range, outputColumn As Range, inputColumnNumber As Long, outputColumnNumber As Long
    Const SEARCH_ROW As Long = 1
    Const INPUT_HEADER As String = "Crude items"
    Const OUTPUT_HEADER As String = "Refined Ones"
    Const START_ROW = 2

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set inputColumn = GetColumnByHeader(ws, SEARCH_ROW, INPUT_HEADER)
    Set outputColumn = GetColumnByHeader(ws, SEARCH_ROW, OUTPUT_HEADER)

    If inputColumn Is Nothing Or outputColumn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    inputColumnNumber = inputColumn.Column
    outputColumnNumber = outputColumn.Column

    With ws
        inputs = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(START_ROW, inputColumnNumber), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, inputColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row, inputColumnNumber)).Value)
        For i = LBound(inputs) To UBound(inputs)
            inputs(i) = GetMatch(re, inputs(i))
        Next
        .Cells(START_ROW, outputColumnNumber).Resize(UBound(inputs), 1) = Application.Transpose(inputs)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetColumnByHeader(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal SEARCH_ROW As Long, ByVal columnName As String) As Range
    Set GetColumnByHeader = ws.Rows(SEARCH_ROW).Find(columnName)
End Function

Public Function GetMatch(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "_(.*)"

        If .test(inputString) Then
            GetMatch = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetMatch = inputString  'or =vbNullString if want to return nothing
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working through an actual table things will become quite easy:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr(), x As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    For Each cl In .Range("Table1[Crude Items]") 'Change Table1 accordingly
         ReDim Preserve arr(x)
         If InStr(cl, "_") > 0 Then
             arr(x) = Split(cl, "_")(1)
         Else
            arr(x) = ""
         End If
         x = x + 1
    Next cl
    .Range("Table1[Refined Ones]").Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

There is a check for "_". If not there, the cell will be kept empty.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can also consider to use formula to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you want to replace "_" character with. For example, iff you replace the following line of your script:

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cel(1, 3).Address) = Split(cel, "_")(1)

with this one:

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cel(1, 3).Address) = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cel, "_", "")

The above line should replace the "_" character with nothing from the cells in the Crude_Items column

And as Lee said, you can also consider using formula in the worksheet if you do not have significant amount of data